# Dynamically allocating number of values to pair objects

Tags: c++

I want to store number of coordinates for a graph and need to allocate it in pairs. How do I dynamically allocate 'n' number of coordinates in pairs?

Comment: By any means possible. Using `std::vector` or  operator `new` for example.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) perhaps?

Comment: What I mean is how to enter multiple set of values using std::pair ?

Comment: `vector.emplace_back(value1, value2)`? Or `vector.push_back(make_pair(value1, value2))`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To instantiate std::pair, you can use that:

```
std::pair<int, double> p2(42, 0.123);
std::cout << "Initialized with two values: "
          << p2.first << ", " << p2.second << '\n';
```

And for vectors :

```
std::vector<int> second (4,100);
```

(This line creates a Vector of 4 int, with value 100. I let you guess what you can do ?)

```
  std::vector<int> third (second.begin(),second.end());
```

This one iterates on another vector. Be creative and don't hesitate to look on docs !
(And also, check the doc for the `operator new`. If you want to create it dynamically you'll need it :) )

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

void doSomething(){
    int x = 1, y= 3;
    // vector of the graph's points
    vector<pair<int, int>> graph;
    // add point to the vector
    graph.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
    // accessing a point // here accessing first point at index 0
    // you can loop through the vector when having many points
    cout<<"x = "<< graph.at(0).first <<endl;
    cout<<"y = "<< graph.at(0).second <<endl;
}
```